# Is there a better way to set up a Unique formula for multiple column and sheet references?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that does a combination formula for multiple columns in a two different tabs. I feel there has to be a better, more efficient, way of producing this formula.

I've included the formula in question referenced in Cell Full List!B2 (see below)

```
=IFERROR(
    UNIQUE(
            {Prepend!A3:CZ;Append!A3:CZ}
          )
        )
        ,"Enter a keyword in the Inputs tab"
)
```

Please advise if there is anything I can do to make this more efficient as well as filter the entirety of the table.

WORKING DOCUMENT CAN BE FOUND HERE
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hsbhKDn-8Q_nPgkTRfWo5BYEzSelge2NLfGWvdqD_-Q

Comment: Is there any reason to add the columns one by one instead of using ranges like `A3:CZ`? It makes the formula unreadable

Comment: I've tried changing that in the formula but couldn't get it to work. The sheet is linked to above

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more on what are you trying to achieve? What is your expected final result?

Comment: I'm trying to collect all the unique results in the following ranges Prepend!A3:CZ & Append!A3:CZ. I am currently able to do this but with a formula that grabs each column range separately. It's very bulky. Is there a way to write this formula more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the function `FLATTEN` ([see reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)). It flattens a range into a single column. So in your case, you may use `{FLATTEN(Prepend!A3:CZ);FLATTEN(Append!A3:CZ)}` to get all the values from both sheets into a single column.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.